# How to create a shortcut for a command in Terminal that I can have in my Dock?

Tags: terminal, big-sur

I'm trying to find out if there is a way of creating a shortcut to the following terminal command - so that I can have it on my Dock (Big Sur)

```
ssh aide199@192.16.1.15
```

Comment: So the Icon should open Terminal and run the command?

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct

Answer (score 7):

In Automator, create a new Application.

In that application, add an action "Run AppleScript"
For the content of that AppleScript,

```
tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "ssh aide199@192.16.1.15"
    end tell
```

Save the application, then in the Finder, drag the new application to the Dock

Comment: `do script "exec ssh ...` to avoid having to quit an additional shell layer.

Comment: if he's ssh-ing in somewhere, I figured he wants to be left in the shell layer, no?

Comment: I would just use **Script Editor** and save the _code_ as an _application_, It may be _six of one, half a dozen of the other_, however, in a use case such as this I believe **Automator** will actual use more resources to accomplish the same task.

Comment: 'doh! Yes, Script Editor would work great. For many contexts, Automator adds functionality of where the script can run; in this case, Script Editor on its own would be absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a new plain text file containing the command you want to run.
2. Name the file with extension `.command`.
3. Save the file somewhere.
4. Set the execute bit on the file with `chmod +x /path/to/file.command`.
5. Drag the file to the Dock, right of the right separator.
6. Opening the file will launch Terminal and run the command.

Comment: Two critical issues with this answer as it's currently written using the _shell command_ shown in the OP:  1. Upon clicking on it in the **Dock** one would get, e.g.: "The file “name.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges." (You need to make the **.command** _file_ executable, e.g. `chmod u+x /path/to/name.command` in **Terminal**) 2. However, once made executable and clicking on it in the **Dock**, one would end up with, e.g.: `% /path/to/name.command ; exit;` and the **Terminal** _window_ would just not usable.

Comment: @user Thanks for the point about chmod I forgot about that, will edit that in. Using the Terminal window created after the command is run wasn’t specified in the question.

Comment: RE: "Using the Terminal window created after the command is run wasn’t specified in the question." --  The _shell command_ in the OP is `ssh aide199@192.16.1.15` and obviously one needs an interactive window with it, otherwise it's useless!

Comment: +1. This won't work for the asker's very specific circumstance, but answers are supposed to be broadly applicable. You might consider adding a note about the terminal window staying open vs closing.